# Repeating Task throws null exception after some repeats

Tags: android, xamarin, service, xamarin.android, background-process

I have a code that runs every minute in an **Activity**, because i have put **KeepScreenOn** Flag i though i can run this method without problem:

```
 private async Task UpdateData(CancellationToken token)
        {
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)this.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(60000);
                // Get ETA
                try
                {
                    query = ParseObject.GetQuery("CaseDetails");
                    results = await query.FindAsync();
                    resultsList = results.ToList();
                    foreach (var temp in resultsList)
                    {
                        // If ETA is changed, Update ETA and vibrate
                        if (Convert.ToDateTime(application.caseObject["ETA"]) != temp.Get<DateTime>("ETA"))
                        {
                            ctsETA.Cancel();
                            ctsETA = new CancellationTokenSource();
                            _tokenETA = ctsETA.Token;
                            application.caseObject = temp;
                            dateDiff = Convert.ToDateTime(application.caseObject["ETA"]) - DateTime.Now;
                            StartCountdownTimer(ctsETA.Token, dateDiff);
                            vibrator.Vibrate(500);
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("Exception occured: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

But some times i get object null exception on *results = await query.FindAsync();* and i cant understand why. Is it because of a problem with the code or because i should use **Background Service** for this?

thanks

For now i have this stacktrace taken frm visual studio log, i was unable to reproduce the problem today, when i will have a better stacktrace i will post again
StackTrace:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime      ... 1 more
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime  Caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.HttpClient+<>c__DisplayClass15.<ExecuteAsync>b__d (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00093] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  Process: com.cdrosos.iSurgery, PID: 11861
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.HttpClient+<>c__DisplayClass15.<ExecuteAsync>b__d (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00093] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime      ... 1 more
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
01-07 20:18:51.894  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   11861   AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in <3dc9ed3d31194319991e686734adcb10>:0 
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-08 04:24:26.846  Samsung GT-I9301I   Error   1785    AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Attach stacktrace.

Comment: try run UpdateData task in background thread like this Task.Run(async () => await UpdateData()); but don't forget wrap all your ui calls like RunOnUiThread(() => vibrator.Vibrate(500));

Comment: @danil thanks for the suggestion, is my approach correct or i should use a service? Also i didnt know that vibrator needs to run on ui, is that why sometimes the vibration never ends?

Comment: @CDrosos you can run your code without create any background services. General idea avoid UpdateData thread mix, and if FindAsync works good only in background thread, run query code in background thread. Also if you need this, you can implement your code in background service without any problem, vibrator must work.

Comment: @CDrosos
note: do not confuse background thread and background service. background thread started with wrap Task.Run(() => { /* some work */ }); but background service its clearly android thing https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/

Comment: yes i know about services, i think android even if i use background thread will kill my activity if it remains paused for a lot of time. I still cant understand this crazy bug with the vibrator that never end vibrate, its like a virus more rather than a bug :D i will try to use runonui thread or use a component to vibrate